# get and append first four images from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

that's pretty much it, how do I get the first four images from whatever url and then append them to a specified element

something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var thing = $.get('thing.html');
thing.slice(0,2).appendTo(".appending");
});
```

Comment: please explain properly and post html...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('document').ready(function () {
     var thing = $.get('HTMLPage.htm',
     function (markup, b) {
       var $page = $(markup);
       $page.each(function (index, item) {
             if (item.tagName == "IMG") {
                $(item).appendTo(".appending");
             }
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   var thing = $.get('thing.html');
   thing.find('img').slice(0,4).appendTo(".appending");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting `thing` to contain HTML, try

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var thing = $.get('thing.html');
    $(thing).filter('img').slice(0,4).appendTo(".appending");
    });
```

`.find('img')` search only in **descendants** so if your `thing` contains `img` direcly It wouldn't work, try `filter()` instead http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/UnNd9/

> **filter()** – search through all the elements.
>    **find()** – search through all the child elements only.
>   http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('thing.html', function(html){
    //depending on what 'html' is made of, you may need to wrap it in a node
    var $imgs = $(html).find('img').slice(0,4);
    $(imgs).appendTo(".appending");
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap them in jQuery, because `.slice()` **[..] Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .slice() method constructs a new jQuery object containing a subset of the elements specified by the start and,[..]** http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: oh, my bad, didn't know jQuery redefined it. Thx for pointing it out.